# Non-overriden abstract-static method does not throw error

Tags: python, abstract-class, abc

i have come across some weird behavior when using ABC library in Python 3.8.10.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractproperty, abstractstaticmethod, abstractmethod
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Message(ABC):
    _type: str = None
    _error: str = None
    _error_msg: str = None

    def error(self):
        return self._error is not None

    def error_msg(self):
        return self._error_msg

    @abstractstaticmethod
    def from_payload(payload: dict):
        """Static initiator of the Message class."""

    @abstractproperty
    def json(self):
        """Returns json string suitable for websocket communication."""

class ActionsLogDetail(Message):
    """Represents detail for one action log from db."""

    def __init__(self, id):
        super().__init__(_type='ActionsLogDetail')
        self.id = id

ActionsLogDetail.from_payload({'x':1})                                                                                                                                                                     
None  # This should raise error and not return None
```

**Well i did some digging in the documentation and found this:**

---

[image]

**But, if I change the code appropriately:**

```
@staticmethod
@abstractmethod
def from_payload(payload: dict):
    """Static initiator of the Message class."""

ActionsLogDetail.from_payload({'x':1})
None  # Still returns None!
```

Well now I am thinking whether it could be maybe due to dataclass, but don't think so. This kind of defeats the purpose and kind of forces me to go back to `raise NotImplementedError` in the parent class, but that lets me initiate, which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that abstract static methods are just weird. You'd *think* that abstract static methods wouldn't be directly callable, or something like that, but that's not what they do. Instead, abstract static methods just make a class abstract, like abstract regular methods.

If you try to instantiate `ActionsLogDetail`, you'll find you can't, because the class has an abstract static method and an abstract property (inherited from the parent and not overridden), so the class is abstract, and `object.__new__` will refuse to create instances of an abstract class. That does absolutely nothing to stop you from calling the abstract static method.

Comment: Well, you are right ofc. It should have occurred to me, but i got mixed up, because I used that staticmethod as a constructor - returning object of that class, therefore somehow thought that I am indeed initiating. Thank you.

Comment: @JanJanáček: *Alternative constructors* are usually implemented a `classmethod`s.